# Splitting a vector/array in R

Tags: arrays, r, vector, split

I would like to use R for performing an operation similar to merge sort. I would like to split my vector/array in to two parts. My input is present in a variable named inp.

```
> inp <- c(5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4)
> inplen <- length(inp)
> left <- inp[1:ceiling(inplen/2)]
> right <- inp[ceiling(inplen/2)+1:inplen]
> left
[1] 5 6 7 8 9
> right
[1]  1  2  3  4 NA NA NA NA NA
> length(left) 
[1] 5
> length(right)
[1] 9
```

Here you can see that though I split the vector in two halves the size of the right half is larger than the size of the left half. Also there are some entries in the right half that have the value NA. I am not able to figure out as to why the second vector created (called right) is having these extra entries.

Answer (score 3):

You are running in to a (well-known) problem caused by a higher operator precedence for ":" than for "+":

```
ceiling(inplen/2)+1:inplen
[1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
```

NAs are being returned because your index exceeded the length of the vector.

Comment: Thanks. I realized the mistake. The problem is with the absence of parenthesis. 

right <- inp[ceiling(inplen/2)+1:inplen]

should be replaced by 

right <- inp[(ceiling(inplen/2)+1):inplen]

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a bracket:

```
right = inp[(ceiling(inplen/2)+1):inplen]
```

To expand, suppose we have

```
1 + 1:3
```

does this mean `1+(1:3)` or `(1+1):3`. R interprets this as `1+(1:3)` so when you type `1+1:3` you get:

```
1 + c(1,2,3)
```

which becomes

```
c(2,3,4)
```

Another common gotcha is:

```
R> x = 1:5
R> x[2:length(x)-1]
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Instead of selecting elements 2 to 4, we have selected elements 1 to 4 by mistake.

Comment: Thanks. I realized the mistake. The problem is with the absence of parenthesis. right <- inp[ceiling(inplen/2)+1:inplen] should be replaced by right <- inp[(ceiling(inplen/2)+1):inplen] –

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` for this, with `cut` to create the breakpoints:

```
split(inp,cut(seq(inplen),breaks=c(0,ceiling(inplen/2),inplen),labels=c("left","right")))
$left
[1] 5 6 7 8 9

$right
[1] 1 2 3 4
```